# Difference between Nativescript timer module and JS setInterval

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript

I'm working on a personal project that uses the setInterval functions.  I noticed Nativescript has the 'timer' module with setInterval and implemented that into my project.

Is it worth importing the Nativescript timer module every time I want to use setInterval() in my app or can I just use the Javascript setinterval() instead?

Example of code ( angular 2 with typescript ):

```
import { setInterval, clearInterval } from 'timer'

/* skip some code */

private setInterval = setInterval;
private clearInterval = clearInterval;

/* skip some code */

time() {
  this.interval = this.setInterval(() => {
   this.duration = this.clock.formatTime(time)
  }, 1)
}
```

source : http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/cookbook/timer

On a side note, is the above way the correct way to implement the timer module? My only experience so far is the Angular 2 - Nativescript tutorial with the color module but the timer module is slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timer module abstracts the native platform timing systems. If you view the [source here for the Android version](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.android.ts#L17) you'll notice the native classes/methods used. As for the naming `setInterval`, `clearTimeout`, etc. that is just what the NativeScript team chose to call those methods. I'm assuming to make it simple for javascript developers to remember what the functions do. I would default to the `timer` module opposed to the JS timeouts/intervals in your NS app, but that's my opinion.

As for importing, your TS code looks good.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply and link. I'll start looking at the source code more often to get a better understanding.

Comment: Worth noting that there is no separate "JS timeouts/intervals". They defer to the timer module: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/globals/globals.ts#L85-L89 (also setTimeout / setInterval isn't actually part of ecmaScript, hence not included by V8 itself, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616102/how-is-settimeout-implemented-in-node-js)